# Checking the range from dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, key-value

```
valid = {'Temp': [10, 55], 'rain_percent': [40, 90]}
Temp = 30.3
Raining = 86. 88
if int(Temp) not in range(valid['Temp'][0], valid['Temp'][1]):
    print "Bad Temp readings"
if int(Raining) not in range(valid['rain_percent'][0], valid['rain_percent'][1]):
    print "Bad Rain Percentage readings"
```

This is how I'm checking if variables `Temp`, `Raining` are within the range of values of respective `keys` within my `valid` dictionary. But the problem here is I have to hardcode it using `valid['Temp'][0]`, `valid['Temp'][1]` with indices `0` and `1`. I know that in python you should never hardcode any indices till there's no option without doing so. Is there any better way of achieving the same output without hard-coding indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use operator chaining here and forgo the range business completely:

```
lower_valid_temp, upper_valid_temp = valid['Temp']
if lower_valid_temp <= Temp <= upper_valid_temp:
    print "..."
```

As an added bonus, this will be more efficient than creating a list (via `range`) and then iterating over it to find (or not find) the value (via the `in` opeartor)